# Method for changing axes limits in plot_PCA (R - Momocs)?

Tags: r, plot, pca, axes

I am trying to find a method for changing the axes limits for plot_PCA in Momocs. It seems it was available in the plot.PCA method, but I cannot figure out how to do it using the plot_PCA function.
The customisation uses the Grindr layers for multivariate plots but I cannot figure out what function is needed to adjust the axes limits.

I hope someone has some idea!

(Example code)

bot.f = efourier(bot, norm = FALSE)

bot.pca = PCA(bot.f)

pdf("bot.pca.pdf")

plot_PCA(bot.pca, axes=c(1, 2), center_origin = FALSE, chullfilled = TRUE, title = "bot practice", labelpoints = TRUE)

dev.off()

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Momocs/versions/1.3.2/topics/plot_PCA
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Momocs/versions/1.3.2/topics/layers

Comment: Would you please provide a minimal reproducible example. See: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: @TarJae Ah yes, my bad!

bot.f = efourier(bot, norm = FALSE)
bot.pca = PCA(bot.f)
pdf("bot.pca.pdf")
plot_PCA(bot.pca, axes=c(1, 2), center_origin = FALSE, chullfilled = TRUE, title = "bot practice", labelpoints = TRUE)
dev.off()

Answer (score 0):

- one cheap option, would be to use "zoom" argument in plot_PCA.
- also plot.PCA is still there !
- finally, I hope to get rid of all of this and provide something more convenient at some point
- feel free to contact me directly should you have any exotic request
  all the best